# Can't fire event "Uncaught ReferenceError: killMedia is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, riot.js

Im making WYSIWYG editor for web magazine with Riot.js.
I want to disply instagram image with delete icon when I click add button and delete instagram image when I click delete icon.

I can disply instagram image with delete icon but cant delete them because function killMedia doesnt work.
When I click delete icon, I get this error message.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: killMedia is not defined

Im working on below code.
Does anyone know what problem is?

```
<div id='body-text' class='body-text' contenteditable=true data-placeholder='Body Contents'></div>

<label>
    <input type='text' name='instagram' placeholder='Input Instagram embed code'>
    <button onclick={ addInstagram }>add</button>
</label>


<script>
addInstagram(e) {
    var embedCode = this.instagram.value

    var instagram = document.createElement('div')
    instagram.setAttribute('class', 'media-frame')
    instagram.setAttribute('show', '{showMedia}')
    instagram.innerHTML = embedCode
    var i = document.createElement('i')
    i.setAttribute('id', 'media-killer')
    i.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-times-circle-o media-killer')
    i.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true')
    i.setAttribute('show', '{showMedia}')
    i.setAttribute('onclick', '{killMedia}')

    var target = document.getElementById('body-text')
    instagram.appendChild(i)
    target.appendChild(instagram)

    this.instagram.value = ''
    this.update()
    this.modal = false
}

this.showMedia = true
killMedia(e) {
    this.showMedia = false
    this.update()
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tags don't go in the title. That's why we have tags. Clive has fixed it for you this time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know that. Thank you for telling me

Comment: I think this is not working because  you are creating the elements dynamically and is not compiled by Riot. Probably you can rethink this in a more RiotJs way. For instance that your tag has an array to store the instagram images, and each instagram image is a tag, with the remove method in it. So instead of doing that plain javascript appendChild and setAttributes you just add elements to an array and remove from it, and the iterate to show them.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using to define the function `killMedia` is incorrect. It seems like Riot.js has some alternative syntax for event handlers, which is why it works for `addInstagram`.

There are several ways to properly declare and define a function in JavaScript. One would be:

```
// declare variable killMedia and assign a function to it
var killMedia = function( e ){
    this.showMedia = false;
    this.update();
}
```

Also, I don't know anything about how Riot.js will call event functions, so, since you are using `this` inside your `killMedia` function, you may need to bind the proper `this` to the function as you declare it. One way to do this is with the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
// declare variable killMedia and assign a function to it
var killMedia = function( e ){
    this.showMedia = false;
    this.update();
}.bind( this );
```

If the syntax is not the problem and Riot.js is handling the special declaration of `killMedia`, you may just need to declare `killMedia` *before* `addInstagram`, i.e. move that function above `addInstagram`. This is just a guess, since I don't know anything about Riot.js.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I tried your way but I got same error, I think it's a problem about RIot.js thing. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

I added this as a comment but now I had time to implement this.
I think that is not working because you are trying to load the elements dynamically so is not compiled by Riot compiler.

A more Riot.js way to do what you want is to build another tag called instagram_image that you can remove, and have an array to iterate the images in the parent tag.

I simplified your code, but the idea is this: 
(here is the plunker version http://plnkr.co/edit/EmkFhq0OyVtwSNIJqeJF?p=preview)

```
<my-tag>
  <span each={img in instagram_images} >
    <instagram_image embed_code={img.embed_code}></instagram_image>
  </span>
  <label>
      <input type='text' name='instagram' placeholder='Input Instagram embed code'>
      <button onclick={ addInstagram }>add</button>
  </label>

  <script>
    this.instagram_images = []

    addInstagram(e) {
        var instagram_image = {embed_code: this.instagram.value}
        this.instagram_images.push(instagram_image)
        this.instagram.value = ''
    }
  </script>
</my-tag>

<instagram_image>
  <div onclick={remove}>
      {opts.embed_code}
  </div>
 <script>

   this.remove = function() {
    this.unmount()
    this.update()
   }
 </script>
</instagram_image>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help!! I just started to use Riot.js so I didn't understand its way. I would like to ask about your way. If I upload 3 instagram image and then click delete icon, unmout <instagram_image>, all 3 images have to be deleted, don't they? I would like to delete only one which I choose..

Comment: No, instagram_image is a tag and each one is a different instance. So if you click over one it will delete just that. Check the plunker link  in the answer. When you write in the input and click add it will add a instagram_image. Do it 3 times and you will have 3 items. Then click over one of them, and it will unmount (or disappear)

Comment: Oh, now I understood what you said and how I use Riot.js. I really appreciate you.
And I'm making WYSIWYG editor like Tumblr's one, there are texts, images, Imstagram, Youtube, Twitter's enbed in one contenteditable div. Not only Instagram, and texts have to be typed in contenteditable div directly.
In that case, we can go same way as yours?

Comment: No, it will require  more thinking. Probably a WYSIWYG editor is doing 2 things, in some place is storing the real structure and how the components related to each other and in another is translating that to html or text, and syncing that. So I think that you need to research more about how to implement that kind of architecture. Or maybe you will need to integrate a third party library like tinyMCE or something.

Comment: I see, I thought so. What I'm doing is putting contenteditable div and I type some texts there directly. And when I insert images, Instagram or Youtube, click each button alongside a contenteditable div, open the modal window and add them by using appendChild like my above code. I manipulate DOM on this part, not virtual one. Is it ok except for firing killMedia?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more,  I recommend you to look at some examples like the dynamic inputs here http://richardbondi.net/riot/ , the live editor http://plnkr.co/edit/wSzhxiUMebvUT0O7UWh9?p=preview or the markdown editor here http://txchen.github.io/feplay/riot_vue/ . Good Luck.

Comment: I see. Really thank you for your kindness!! I will learn more with that pages.